# Beginner: How to return user input?

Tags: java, class, variables, input, types

I'm new to Java and I'm having trouble with this bit of code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BattleshipLogic {

    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;

    private final boolean[][] hits;
    private final boolean[][] ships;

    public BattleshipLogic(int numRows, int numCols) {
        this.rows = numRows;
        this.cols = numCols;

        this.hits = new boolean[rows][cols];
        this.ships = new boolean[rows][cols];
    }

    public void startGame() {
        placeShips();
        boolean gameOver = false;
        // draw field for the first time
        drawUI();

        while (!gameOver) {
            Target target = askForTarget();
            processTarget(target);
            drawUI();
        }
    }

    private Target askForTarget() {
        Target t = new Target();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your target:");
        t = input.nextInt();
        return t;
    }

    /*
     * This is just an example. You have to draw the ships by yourself.
     * If you don't like the way the UI is drawn, make your own stuff!
     */
    private void drawUI() {
        // draw the ui, see blatt01/oberflÃ¤che.txt for an example
        System.out.println("Schiffeversenken");
        System.out.println("================");
        System.out.println();

        // columns
        System.out.print("    ");
        for (int col = 0; col < this.cols; col++) {
            System.out.print(col + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("   _");
        for (int col = 0; col < this.cols; col++) {
            System.out.print("__");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 0; row < this.rows; row++) {
            System.out.print(Character.toChars(3 + row));
            System.out.print(" |");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private void placeShips() {
        // do useful stuff to place the ships here
        // see Blatt01 for rules
    }

    private void processTarget(Target target) {

    }

    /**
     * This class only holds the position
     * of a target.
     */
    private class Target {

        public int row;
        public int col;
    }
}
```

Everytime I try to compile this error comes up:

error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to BattleshipLogic.Target

I know that the types are different, but what kind of a type is Target? **How can I get the user input to be assigned to t?**

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What is this Target class? Does it have any setter methods that take an int? Or a constructor that takes an int? Also side issue: you don't want to keep creating new Scanner objects based on System.in each time you need input. Create one and pass it around where needed.

Comment: I'd assume you need to return `new Target(input.nextInt())`, but for that you would need an appropriate constructor in Target class. The code of Tarhet would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are assigning an int to the variable t of type Target when you do "t = input.nextInt()". Showing us the class definition for target would be helpful.

Comment: How exactly would I add a constructor? I've added the whole code this time!

Comment: This whole question really means that you need to study the most basic rudiments of the language. Our giving you a specific code answer will not help you in this, but rather it needs to be effort from  you. You won't regret doing this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best answered by studying the first chapters of any intro to Java tutorial or textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this.

```
 private Target askForTarget() {
            Target t = new Target();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter your target:");
            t.row = input.nextInt();
            t.col = input.nextInt();
            return t;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to assign the int value to

> t of type Target

you need a

> getter and setter method

on your t

e.g.

```
public class Target
{
  private int myValue;
  public void setMyValue(int myValue)
  {
     this.myValue=myValue;
  }
  public int getMyValue()
 {
      return myValue;
 }
}
```

then in your askForTarget() method

```
t.setMyValue(input.nextInt());
return t;
```

if you ever want to use the int in t in other calling method you can use the t method

```
t.getMyValue();
```